# How to make space in the middle of row in a for loop?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, range

How can I create space between row 2 and 3, so that the rows are still defined as row 2 and row 3. The column has the range: 8 and row has the range 4.

This is what I got:

```
column = 8
row = 4
def print_seats(board):
    """print board"""
    for i in range(column):
        for j in range(row):
            if j > 0:
                print(' ', end='')
            print(board[i][j], end='')
        print()

def create_board():
    """create a new board of dimensions DIMxDIM"""
    board = []
    for i in range(column):
        new_row = []
        for j in range(row):
            new_row.append('_')
        board.append(new_row)
    return board


board = create_board()
print_seats(board)
```

This is what I'm expecting:

```
- -  - -
- -  - -
- -  - -
- -  - -
- -  - -
- -  - -
- -  - -
- -  - -
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extra print statement before printing out the third row.

```
def print_seats(board):
    """print board"""
    for i in range(column):
        for j in range(row):
            if j > 0:
                print(' ', end='')
            # if row 2, add an extra space before the _
            # 2 because range() starts with index 0, so 2 is the third row
            if j == 2:
                print(' ', end='')
            print(board[i][j], end='')
        print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the looping and use:

```
def print_seats(board):
    """print board"""
    for item in board:
        for i, x in enumerate(item):
            if i == 1:
                print(x, end = '  ')
            else:
                print(x, end = ' ')
        print()
```